# MPMoviePlayerViewController display incorrect controls with live streaming on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have an application which shows live streams. It works well on iOS 6 and 7 but not on iOS 8.

The controls of the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` used to have the bullet defining the time on the timeline (2 on picture) to the right because we are live and we cannot go further in the stream. It also used to show "Live" at the right of the timeline when the stream is watching live (1 on picture).

Here is how it looks **correctly** on iOS 6:

[image: Live streaming on iOS 6]
[image: Live streaming on iOS 6 when going back in the stream]

Here is how it looks **badly** on iOS 8:

[image: Live streaming on iOS 8 with controls not correctly displayed]

After searching the net, is does not seems something have changed in the API's of iOS8 for that.
Is it a known bug of iOS 8?

Thanks for help!

Comment: The same problem with streaming on iOS8